# 'Strange' PHP Comparison behavior

Tags: php

This may not be strange behaviour at all, actually, but to me (Coming from java) it certainly is, here's the code that I'm using.

```
echo "</br>Category: " . $category . " -- Image: " . $image;
if(($category != 1) && ($image == 1)) {
    echo "</br>Problem.";
}
```

Granted this has been stipped down, the following output is this:

```
Category: 6 -- Image: 4
Problem.
```

I'm not sure what the reasoning for this is, considering the use of the "&&" and not the "||" operator, I'm almost positive this is correct. Perhaps PHP has different conditions for when comparing integers? Is this the same as saying

```
if category is 6 AND image is present
```

like a

```
if(image)
```

call would in JavaScript?

I'm at a loss of ideas here.

Reproducement code below:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "xx.xx.xxx.xxx") { // Developer mode
        die('<h1>Oops, something went wrong, please wait while we fix it!</h1>');
    }

    $category = 6;
    $image = 4;
    echo "</br>Category: " . $category . " -- Image: " . $image;
    if(($category != 1) && ($image == 1)) {
        echo "</br>Problem.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error: http://3v4l.org/bAhef ; Show us your real code &| add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and look if you get any errors

Comment: Try to `var_dump($expression)` your variables like `$category`. And update your question with that output!

Comment: $Rizier - No errors, The problem persists when running reproducement code on my machine(Albeit not on the 3v4l)

Comment: @Christian.tucker Is this shown code the **entire** and **real** code? Also note: `Restart whatever isn't working` <- This solves 75% of every problem :D

Comment: @Rizier123 - Oh wow. Restarted apache and everything started working perfectly fine. It was driving me mad for almost an hour, to the point I finally posted a simplistic question like this, :facepalm:

Comment: @Christian.tucker Nice :D! Just remember this: [How to fix stuff working in IT](http://itsfunny.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/How-I-fix-stuff-working-in-IT.jpg) <-SO is the weird IT vooodooo. *It was driving me mad for almost an hour* I know how [this](http://en.docsity.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/programmers-be-like.jpg) looks. (BTW: Since this can't be reproduced it doesn't serve anyone so i would delete it)

Comment: @Rizier - I can't, because there are answers.

Answer (score 0):

I can not replicate error,
I am only getting:

```
Category: 6 -- Image: 4
```

since `(6!=1 AND 4==1)` is `FALSE`

Comment: This doesn't serve anyone

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be OK. But just try with the following code.

```
$category = (int)6;
$image = (int)4;
echo "</br>Category: " . $category . " -- Image: " . $image;
if(($category !== 1) && ($image === 1)) {
    echo "</br>Problem.";
}
```

[More comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)